# C++ operator technique

Tags: c++, methods

It was mentioned on stack overflow by a programmer that if you declare one class function, for example:

```
operator++()
```

That for user-interface purposes (as the user naturally assumes its opposite should work), you should declare the other:

```
operator--()
```

Is there a link to an article that supports this? I wish to be able to reference it to other programmers.

I thought to add that, perhaps the suggestion is similar to the [rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), or [the big 2](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/bigtwo.html).

In light of hostilefork's answer, perhaps the opposite functions should be declared even in instances where even it doesn't serve a purpose, but as private, so the user explicitly knows they cannot call that function? Or is that just being pedantic?

Comment: It certainly makes sense to me when you are talking about comparison operators (< > == etc) so that any comparison can work. But for ++ and --, you may have reasons for only implementing one of those.

Comment: Indeed. I've had cases where I've only needed to add singular features. Just want to see if there is a reference for it with more details, as it's a valid design suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One hard thing about C++ and operator overloading is that it can be sort of a pun.  Overloading assignment created a bit of a pickle with `auto_ptr`, because code that tried to take "assignment" for granted was being surprised by assigning A to B and then finding immediately afterward that A != B.

http://hostilefork.com/2009/07/10/smart-pointer-casting-study/

I'll point out if the following generalized code will compile, the users of a class will often assume it wouldn't assert:

```
SomeType foo (...);
SomeType bar (foo);
foo++; // let's say we know this is safe
foo--; // then we'd generally hope this is safe also
assert(foo == bar); // ...and this is true
```

There's no law enforcing that, though.  Some people are vocal about it being bad to be tolerating such a a semantic free-for-all:

http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/operator.html

I'd lean toward saying it's important to maintain some of those expectations.  But there's nothing wrong with not compiling a program where decrementing shouldn't have meaning.  Forward iterator was mentioned, perfect example.

The foundational things that you get with languages tend to be very "mathematical" and "symmetric" (like an integer is unlikely to have addition but not subtraction).  But I think that classes that are being tailored to solve specific problems trend toward getting greater value from being *asymmetrical*.

It's sort of the generality-vs-specificity thing.  Think about an application that's close to the user.  They don't want all things to be equally accessible...more common operations should be "easy" while infrequent operations can be marginalized a bit.  Some of the most frustrating software is that which isn't focused on the common case.  Specialized classes that are there to solve a problem are often going to be a lot less symmetrical than General Purpose Language constructs or libraries.

Comment: Excellent depth of answer. Your comment `//then we'd generally hope this is safe also` highlights the fact that maybe the opposite operator should be declare, **but** (and a big but there) as private, so if the user tries to call it, they know explicitly it isn't a valid command even if say ++ is.

Comment: Glad you like it, I wish there were more opportunities to wax philosophical on StackOverflow.  :)  As for declaring things private vs. not declaring, I was generally of the opinion that was useful in cases of disabling defaults (like default copy constructors)...what is the difference you have in mind for the ++/-- case?

Comment: I think philosophical discussions would be useful in expanding knowledge. I was thinking it more for disabling ++/--, however, ++/-- is disabled by default - so perhaps to inform the user that you're aware of the function but it's been purposefully disabled?

Comment: Well C++ error messages aren't known for being what I call "terra firma"!  Here's another philosophical-type article that might speak to you: http://hostilefork.com/2009/06/16/eight-year-olds-should-read-code/

Comment: Intriguing article. I'm in C++ chat if you want to discuss.

Answer (score 7):

That depends heavily on the semantics of the class. For example, forward iterators will always define operator++, but never operator--.

If it makes as much sense to increment something as it does to decrement it, then I agree with the original statement, but there are certainly cases where one makes sense and the other does not.

Answer (score 4):

I would say the advice is inaccurate.

A counter-example would be a forward iterator.  For example, an iterator over a singly-linked list can't go backwards, so operator--() would make no sense.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think if you declare one operator (say `operator ++()`) then you have to declare the other one (`operator --()`). It's always on need basis. If you need `operator --()` then declare it.

> the user naturally assumes its opposite should work

There are some cases where this statement is not true. For example, your program is ticking with every hour passed and doing some stuff. Here only `operator ++()` can be applicable. `operator --()` is not even possible.

Answer (score 2):

Why? Not even the standard forward iterator has both :-)

Comment: Why? As given, if the user believes they can use ++, they should have --. Likewise, it was offered if you have += you should have -= (I note the word should). The advice makes sense in context of classes where it should support it. I'd be curious as to why there is a one-way iterator? I will add the advice offered above was a rebuttal to a particular class design I had, so it's intriguing to see support to non-symmetric designs.

Comment: @SSight3: for example `istream_iterator` is one-way, since you can't necessarily rewind an input stream. Specifically it's an InputIterator, not even a ForwardIterator.

Comment: @SSight3: There are one-way iterators because there are containers(or container-like objects) that cannot be iterated backwards.  Like singly-linked lists, and some types of streams.

Answer (score 1):

The most important advice that you can get when providing operators is that programming is about modelling a *domain*, and you should do whatever is natural in your *domain*. If in your domain the object that is being modeled by that type can be both incremented and decremented, then your *design* should support both operations, if in the *domain* only one of the operations is present, then providing the reverse operation in the *design* will confuse your users.

Programming is not about throwing code at a compiler so that it can be executed, but about solving a particular problem. Think on the problem at hand, and work from there on in the most natural way. And overall follow the [Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), because that is what is going to make your interfaces easier to use correctly and harder to use incorrectly.